# Indesign Data Merge. Manipulate single Target File From Master Document without creating Individual .indd.

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I'm curious if there is an option to manipulate a single Document/Data-Set from the Data-Merge-Sets without the need to export all the Files to individual .indd's. 
In My special case i'd like to change the letter-spacing for a single data set due lack of space without the possibility to change the text, cause the client insists on that special phrasing. 
I know i can just export all the indd's and refit the text after the fact, but i'm curious if it's possible before the export stage. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK The only way to perform this automatically is to create a new column for this specific case, and apply a different paragraph style to this data field.

Not sure it's less time consuming than adjusting the merged document, but that's your call.

EDIT:
Or you can use a grep style to apply a character style to text with a certain amount of characters (see example below with 35 characters or more):
[image]

Comment: thanks mate ! its a pity that there is not such a thing as an "Exeption-Tag" for Data Merge

Comment: @The_Higgs_Boson see edited answer